# stuck at PXE boot dracut command (PXELINUX DEFAULT) on Virtual Box

Tags: dhcp, virtualbox, pxe-boot

My Setup:

Virtual Box Version 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.6.2)

Windows Version: 10

Running Two VM's :

1 VM : Centos 7 hosting DNS, TFTP, DHCP, HTTPD with two network card --> 1 card Host-only Adapter without DHCP / 2 card bridge adapter

2 VM : Booting with Network card --> Host-Only Adapter

I am trying to install CoreOS from PXE boot installation (need same IP always so using 1 VM DHCP server) .

First Problem : Was able to get IP from DHCP but tftp was not working --> After changing Adapter type from Intel to PCnet PXE boot installation start working.

Current Problem:

Once it picked up option from PXE menu and start loading the images ..... during initial startup where PXELINUX default kickstart command come ... it stuck and not move further.  I have attached the screenshot for the same.

[https://ibb.co/PNzJnjY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imzOD.png)

What i have observed:

I have started pinging the 2 VM which will start pinging during DHCP and PXE boot ... but it will stop pinging once it moves from PXE Boot Menu option. So if network is not reachable that mean KS will not work.

I have applied the same Host-only adapter on both VM's with different MAC. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Please help me out on the same.

Thanks
Rana

Answer (score 1):

When you PXE boot a client its PXE ROM/Firmware performs a DHCP transaction in order to get an IP and the PXE info.

Next it transfers and executes the TFTP retrieved NBP (Network Boot program) which is usually a Boot Manager displaying a boot menu.

Next you select a menu option and the PXE engine TFTP transfers a Kernel and Initrd.

Next the Kernel is started and it performs a new DHCP transaction just only getting an IP and no PXE parameters this time.

In your case it seems the last DHCP transaction is failing or just not performed then you see only the printout of the kernel command line but no the start up of any NIC getting its IP.

Wireshark can help you to see this at network packet level.

The second DHCP transaction usually fails because:

1. Bad parameters in the Kernel command line
2. The kernel/initrd set does not include the needed NIC driver/s
3. The DHCP transaction is trying to use the wrong NIC in a multi-homed PC/VM
4. The init script and associated script engine (i.e. dracut) presents a buggy PXE implementation
5. etc.